# POSTed Excel file getting lost

Tags: html, node.js, post, flask

I have a form that reads a file:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" is="iron-form" method="post" action="http://localhost:7733/receivedoc" id="restForm" >
        <px-file-upload 
          id="uploadComponentId"
          message="Drag and drop files here, or click the button below." 
          multiple=false 
          accept=".xls,.xlsx">
        </px-file-upload>
        <button id="saveDataSetButton">
          <i class="fa-briefcase">Generate Pacing File</i>
        </button>
      </form>
```

Here the `px-file-upload` component is essentially just a re-styling of a standard HTML5 `<input type=file>` element, and I should be able to use it in the same way - the `files` property of `px-file-upload` contains a `FileList` array that I should be able to access and process with a request.

I am trying to post the file with some NodeJS code:

```
  this.$.saveDataSetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(uploadComponentId.files[0])
    console.log('restForm.saveDataSetButton click')
    restForm.submit();
  });
```

As expected, the console DOES show the file being attached (Chrome Console output for `console.log(uploadComponentId.files[0])`):

> File(12233) {name: "testfile.xlsx", lastModified: 1522075602000,
>   lastModifiedDate: Mon Mar 26 2018 16:46:42 GMT+0200 (CEST),
>   webkitRelativePath: "", size: 12233, …}

However, by the time the request gets to the server, it's empty (see below). I'm trying to receive the file via a Flask server (needs to be Flask, will do some Python to the Excel later):

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/Users/user/Documents/flask_min'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['xls', 'xlsx'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/receivedoc', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("In there")
        print(request.files)
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return ('', 204)
```

The server DOES get the request, but it cannot find the file. The console output on the server reads:

> In there
>
> ImmutableMultiDict([])
>
> http://localhost:7733/receivedoc' [POST]>
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2018 15:15:23] "POST /receivedoc HTTP/1.1" 302 -
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2018 15:15:23] "GET /receivedoc HTTP/1.1" 204 -

So apparently the file part doesn't reach the server. Why? What am I missing? How can I send the file?